# Почему нельзя править pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Создал maven проект в eclipse. Помимо того, что он maven, он также еще и JavaFX проект. Нашел в интернете статью, в которой сказано, что если необходимо сделать такой проект, то в файл pom.xml необходимо добавить дополнительный плагин.
Но eclipse не дает возможности править конфигурационный файл. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Это точно, что eclipse не дает править pom.xml ? Что-то я первый раз такое слышу.

Comment: Не использовать eclipse :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто в блокноте добавить плагин, если с eclipse что-то не так. Также, в eclipse нужно перейти на вкладку pom.xml (внизу окна) для редактирования.

Answer (score -1):

`pom.xml` можно править вручную, а так же с помощью встроенных средств eclipse.
*Щелчок ПКМ по `pom.xml` → редактировать*.